# Number of sessions connected to database

Tags: oracle

I need to know how many sessions was connected in a period of time for each snapshot.  Is this possible in Oracle?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find this information in `DBA_HIST_RESOURCE_LIMIT`. Using this view requires the Diagnostic Pack option.

For example, sessions in the last 1 day:

```
select
  s.instance_number,
  s.end_interval_time,
  rn.current_utilization
from
  dba_hist_snapshot s
  join dba_hist_resource_limit rn on (s.snap_id = rn.snap_id and s.instance_number = rn.instance_number)
where
  rn.resource_name = 'sessions'
  and s.end_interval_time > sysdate - 1
order by
  s.end_interval_time
;

INSTANCE_NUMBER END_INTERVAL_TIME         CURRENT_UTILIZATION
--------------- ------------------------- -------------------
              1 07-JUL-16 03.00.23.658 PM                  74
              1 07-JUL-16 04.00.25.330 PM                  74
              1 07-JUL-16 05.00.27.072 PM                  74
              1 07-JUL-16 06.00.28.807 PM                  73
              1 07-JUL-16 07.00.30.589 PM                  73
              1 07-JUL-16 08.00.32.354 PM                  73
              1 07-JUL-16 09.00.34.187 PM                  73
              1 07-JUL-16 10.00.36.100 PM                  79
              1 07-JUL-16 11.00.38.061 PM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 12.00.39.854 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 01.00.41.673 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 02.00.43.523 AM                  75
              1 08-JUL-16 03.00.45.355 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 04.00.47.141 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 05.00.48.895 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 06.00.50.639 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 07.00.52.367 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 08.00.54.128 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 09.00.55.850 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 10.00.57.572 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 11.00.59.295 AM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 12.00.00.949 PM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 01.00.02.704 PM                  73
              1 08-JUL-16 02.00.04.485 PM                  73
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the required Diagnostic Pack also requires the enterprise edition.

Comment: I have seen the MAX_UTILIZATION column and I have a question. The current and max utilization are distinct. What is the diference between them?.

Comment: @estonolose `MAX_UTILIZATION` is the maximum value since the instance startup.

Answer (score 3):

You can find this in `v$session`:

```
select count(*)
from   v$session;
```

It shows you how many sessions are there at this very moment. If you need it for statistical/historical reasons then you need to create a procedure, using this SQL, that runs every x-time and store the result in a table.

You can also install the *Oracle Diagnostics Pack*. This has the *Active Session History* feature that logs every second and 'dumps' the active sessions and relevant information about each of them. This is however an extra payable option.

Comment: I want a historical between two dates. I don't want the sessions now.

Comment: You could have a schedule that runs an insert similar to that query and also includes the sysdate, inserting into a reporting table:

`insert into monitoring_id.session_counts (select sysdate, count(*) from v$session);`